# What is the meaning of a bounded operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

What can be said about it's eigenvalues and trace ?

Since my question has been told to be too broad please tell me required referenced where I can find my answer

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing, if the only information you have is that the operator is bounded.